# Stopword segmentation

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I have a problem with nltk stopwords: if I do a cycle, stopword check on letter and not on word. How I can change this behaviour?

An example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import nltk

stopword = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('italian')
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

df = pd.read_csv('esempioTweet.csv', sep =',')

def remove_stop(text):
    text = [word for word in text if word not in stopword]
    return text
df['Testo_no_stop'] = df['Testo_token'].apply(lambda x: remove_stop(x))
df.head()
```

given a previous column like this:

```
[covid, calano, i, nuovi, contagi, e, tamponi]
```

I expect an output like this:

```
[covid, calano, nuovi, contagi, tamponi]
```

but I have an output like:

```
[v,d,n, ...]
```

I understand that stopword is operating on a single letter and not on the whole word, but why? I'm sure that my remove_stop function works in a right way, but why stopword operates in a wrong one?

Comment: print `stopword` and it's probably a string, i.e. not a list. or print `df['Testo_token']` that may be a word

Comment: @balmy I tried also to define a new string as `prova = "oggi piove e non esco`, but also in this case stopword operates on single letter and not on single words

Comment: That happens when e.g. `for ch in "I come in peace":` you get individual letters. You're expecting more like `for word in ["I","come","in","peace"]:` to iterate on words. Please put a couple of sample rows of your csv into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses `for word in text` which if text is a string returns one letter at a time.

I simplified the code removing pandas as irrelevant - changed your remove_stop slightly to use `word in text.split()`, although I imagine nltk may have a method to split text into words which maybe you should use as for example it might remove punctuation which `split()` won't.

```
import nltk

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('italian')

phrase = "oggi piove e non esco"

def remove_stop(text):
    global stopwords
    text = [word for word in text.split() if word not in stopwords]
    return text

res = remove_stop(phrase)
print( f"{res=}" )
```

Output:

```
res=['oggi', 'piove', 'esco']
```

BTW I don't think you need the lambda, just use:

```
df['Testo_no_stop'] = df['Testo_token'].apply(remove_stop)
```

Don't forget you can add debugging to a function like `remove_stop()`, which TBH is a good reason to use for loops rather than undebuggable comprehensions.

Similarly you can print `stopwords` to check it is a list. It is.

Comment: I chanced upon your profile today. Just a quick bit of feedback on the deletion of comments, which may be of interest. There is a widespread community view here that comments are temporary ("ephemeral" in the parlance) and thus it is true that they can disappear. I've been mildly ticked-off too, where a comment deletion has stopped me finding something I interacted with. But it is good to let this go, since it is not terribly important in terms of the collective aims of the site (creating and maintaining high-quality programming Q&A).

Comment: On the question of whether moderators are accountable; they are elected by the community. They also interact with each other, and with Community Moderators (paid employees) in private chatrooms. Elected Mods often will mount a defence of an action at Meta Stack Overflow. Community Moderators can also be contacted directly. So, there does seem to be several avenues for oversight.